# direct definition of the Radon-Nikodym derivative?

Tags: measure-theory, derivatives, lebesgue-integral

The Radon-Nikodym derivative $f$ for a measurable space $(X,F)$ and measures $\mu,\nu$ where $\nu$'s support contains $\mu$'s support, is defined as follows:

$$\frac {d\mu}{d\nu}(x)=f(x) \text { s.t. }\quad \forall A\in F: \quad \mu(A)=\int_A fd\nu$$

My question is: **Can we also define the Radon-Nikodym derivative "directly"? i.e. as follows:**

$$f(x):=...$$

I am looking for something analogous to the classical derivative in real analysis which is defined as

$$\frac {dF(x)}{dx}=f(x)=\lim_{d\to 0}\frac {F(x+d)-F(x)}{d}$$

Rather than:
$$\frac {dF(x)}{dx}=f(x) \text { s.t. }\quad \forall a,b\in \mathbb R: \quad F(b)-F(a)=\int_a^b f(x)dx$$

**EDIT:**

I came up with the following idea, but it only works for some measurable spaces:
Take a sequence of sets $A_n$ that are both $\mu$ and $\nu$ measure positve for all $n$, such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n=\{x \}$. Then
$$f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {\mu(A_n)}{\nu(A_n)}$$

However, out of the examples I've checked, this only works for discrete measurable spaces (in which case the definition is useless anyway), and one-dimensional continuous measure spaces (not sure if it works for all of them, only the examples I picked). It already fails in the measure space $(\mathbb R^2, B)$ because the value you get depends on how you approach the limit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\nu$ is a positive Radon measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mu$ is a $\mathbb{R}^m$-valued Radon measures in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then
for $\nu$-a.e. $x$ the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\mu$ with respect to $\nu$ is given by
$$
f(x) = \lim_{r\to 0} \frac{\mu(B_r(x))}{\nu(B_r(x))}.
$$
(This result is known as Besicovitch derivation theorem.)

Comment: What is $B_r$? Ball of radius$ r$?

Comment: Also, is there a more general result that doesnt rely on a metric? (Sjnce of course not all measurable spaces are metric spaces)

Comment: Also, does the limit necessarily exist?

Comment: $B_r(x)$ is the ball centered at $x$ and with radius $r$. The limit exists for $\nu$-a.e. $x$ (this is part of Besicovitch's theorem). You can use more general sets (the so-called nicely shrinking sets). I do not know whether there is a more general (i.e., non metric) result.

Comment: Interesting. This makes me wonder: If the limit exists almost everywhere, then what if we have a $\mu$ such that $\mu([a,b])=F(b)-F(a)$ where $F(x)$ is nowhere-differentiable. Can we then still find the Radon-Nikodym derivative of this nowhere differentiable function?

Comment: In general you have that $\mu = f\nu$ (i.e. $\mu(A) = \int_A f d\nu$) if $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\nu$ (i.e., if $\nu(A) = 0$ implies $\mu(A) = 0$), otherwise there is also a singular part in the Radon-Nikodym decomposition of $\mu$: $\mu = f \nu + \mu^s$, where $\mu^s$ is orthogonal to $\nu$.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know what the Radon-Nikodym derivative of this nowhere differentiable $F$ (w.r.t. say the lebesgue measure) would be/how it should be interpreted?

Comment: If $F$ is e.g. the Cantor-Vitali functions and $\nu$ is the Lebesgue measure, then you get $f = 0$ and $\mu^s = \mu$.

Comment: @Programmer2134 If $F$ is nowhere differentiable then there is no such measure.

Comment: Is there an analogous statement for vector measures?